# Blocking the movement of an object in a boundary

Tags: javascript, joystick

I am trying to make an web application that would simulate a joystick control. I have managed to generate 2 circles on click. (one stationary as a boundary and another following my mouse cursor as a joystick). Right now I am trying to figure out how to restrict the joystick movement inside the generated boundary. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="eye"> </div>
    <div class="ball">

    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var balls = document.getElementsByClassName("ball");
    document.onmousemove = function () {
        var x = event.clientX + "px";
        var y = event.clientY + "px";
        // event.clientX => gets the horizontal coordinate of the mouse
        // event.clientY => gets the vertical coordinate of the mouse
        // window.innerWidth => gets the browser width
        // window.innerHeight => gets the browser height

        for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            balls[i].style.left = x;
            balls[i].style.top = y;
            balls[i].style.transform = "translate(x , y)"
        }
```

Comment: Code is not complete. Please revise your question... Do not use getElementsByClassName when you are targeting one element... which is all in this case. use document.querySelector("ball")

Comment: Also, you should probably use a param - usually a var named e - in your event handler too, instead of going off the global event object; it works either way though.  Additionally, the loop only seems useful if updating a bunch of balls, but you don't need to do this by editing the style, as you can go for the property directly, and in fact, if you were doing this with canvas that could cause skewing issues.  I tried to help, so I wrote an answer, but, I was feeling helpful, and more code and clarity would help you get better answers from other people.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe quickest solution is to divide x to a number. Tricky but should work.

```
balls[i].style.left = x /10;
balls[i].style.top = y/10;
```

and why do you need that loop? It will prevent this solution.

Answer (score 0):

At a mouse click xs and ys are taken as datum points.

```
        if (x < xs - barrierDist) {
        x = xs - barrierDist;}
    else if (x > xs + barrierDist) {
        x = xs + barrierDist;}
    else {
        x = x;}
    /*      barrier for y movement*/
    if (y < ys - barrierDist) {
        y = ys - barrierDist;}
    else if (y > ys + barrierDist) {
        y = ys + barrierDist;}
    else {
        y = y;}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to take into account the placement of the graphic element for the joystick, and you can probably do without the etra else {x=x;} and else {y=y;}